# Настройка SSH в Ubuntu server 10.04 (VMware)

Tags: ssh, vmware

Подскажите что делаю не так, ситуация следующая: хочу установить в Ubuntu OpenSSH
c помощью команды sudo apt-get install openssh-server, но в результате получаю ошибку:
Package openssh-server has no installation candidate.

PS openssh-client установлен.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У меня была такая же ошибка, когда устанавливаемый пакет не был в официальных (предустановленных в конфигах) репозиториях. Но openssh-server как раз из официальных.

Проверь список репозиториев: /etc/apt/sources.list и после редактирования apt-get update.

Не буду претендовать на полноту ответа, но мне это помогло - добавлял вручную.
У вас он возможно поврежден. Для устранения вопросов выложите плиз весь вывод консоли до строчки

```
E: Package openssh-server has no installation candidate.
```

Comment: Да спасибо, только что нашел такое же решение проблемы.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте установить виртуальный пакет ssh (sudo aptitude install ssh). Он должен подтянуть в зависимостях и сервер, и клиент.

Comment: в зависимостях будет установка openssh-server и опять же openssh-server has no installation candidate